# How to render script tag in json.erb template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following json data in json.erb template and included the script tag with it. I get invalid json response after including the script tag. What is wrong with the code below.

```
{
  "name" : <%= @name %>,
  "totalRecords" : <%= @all_records %>,
  "filteredRecords" : <%= @filteredRecords %>,
  "data" : [
    <%= render partial: "user_list", collection: @users %>
  ]
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectall').click(function () {
      //  .....
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't include `<script>` or any other tags in your JSON. That would make it invalid.

Also, don't forget to wrap your text values into quotes. Otherwise, your JSON will be invalid.

```
{
  "name" : "<%= @name %>",
  "etc.": "...",
```

To dynamically **load and execute a javascript file**, you can use [`jQuery.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) method or dynamically create a `script` type in javascript (if you don't use jQuery in your project).

```
$.getScript('js/your-javascript.js');
```

Comment: Do you think of any alternative? I must include javascript as there is some javascript code that the page needs.

Comment: Load it separately as a javascript. Also, don't forget to wrap your strings into quotes. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Kumar added an alternative as you requested.

Comment: Will try it out by using.getScript

Answer (score 0):

You can render JSON from your controller with:

```
def show
  ... # setup code
  render json: @my_json_structure
end
```

This will allow you to hit the show action from an AJAX request.  Let me know if I can give you more information.

Comment: i get the json response properly, but once i keep the javascript <script> tag in json.erb file, it raises invalid json response.

Comment: JSON files are not HTML and cannot serve script or JavaScript code.

Comment: ok good to know. Is there any alternative to include the script tag?

Comment: serve an HTML document and use the @json structure in the <script> tag.

     `<script>
       var json = @json

       //execute some code
     </script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want script tag or need ro run js in response i think you should use js.erb and make json object on controller that object you can use on js.erb